What is the purpose of having multiple routing tables with Netplan?
I haven't been able to understand the purpose of assigning (multiple, different) routing tables to routes, or routing-policies in Netplan. I understand you have to route certain source and/or target IP-Addresses into certain interfaces and VLANS etc., but what has this to do with routing tables? What effect has the assignment of a table on the routing?
Maybe my misunderstanding comes specifically from using Netplan. The routes and routing-policies are already YAML-nested inside their respective interfaces/vlans (etc.). Doesn't this already mean the routes and routing policies are scoped to that interface? Why do I need yet another criteria like a table number? And if tables are indeed internally used to route by (real or virtual) interface, shouldn't Netplan create and assign the tables automatically from its YAML nesting scopes?
RTFM-Pointers very welcome, my inability to find high level conceptual documentation or a recent good book is frustrating.

Routing tables are only necessary if you have different traffic on your system, to be sent to the same IP address, that should be sent via a different interface (and route).  They are not necessary in the common case.

what do you mean by "different traffic"? Can you provide a link to an example?

The point is this is a complex routing special case which you don't need.

Finally found some semblance of high level doc: http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html#ss9.6
Seems classical routing can only be based on destination address. If you need other criteria, such as a source address, you need policy based routing. In Linux, policy based routing is implemented with rules that funnel traffic into different tables. Then in these different tables, you can add destination-only based routes. In multi-subnet/vlan  (e.g. cloud networking) scenarios, source address based routing makes sense to ensure symmetrical in/out routes (stateful firewalls). Makes sense?
